# Turbo Studio virtualization

Tags: windows, virtualization

I'm in the process of building a program that has several external libraries and extensions outside of the main program files. My projects total size is 134.2 MB. I would like to make a portable version of it with Turbo Studio, but I face one glaring problem; After capturing the files and building the project I'm left with a 138.9MB executable. The program *does* run, but I don't want it to be so bloated.

I would like to bundle the bulk of the data as a separate `.dat` payload (or equivalent) but I can't seem to find any means of doing this **with** Turbo Studio. VMware ThinApp and Cameyo both do this automatically after the project exceeds a certain size, but it would appear that Turbo Studio doesn't.

Any help with is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a hack I had discovered some time ago that did exactly what you were asking.
It appears that the site that described it is not online anymore so read on.

1. Install your application while monitoring with TurboStudio.
2. If there are multiple entry points (e.g., a suite like office may have
   shortcuts for excel, word etc) then make sure there are shortcuts for those entry points in the Start Menu. If there are not, then click Start, right click on All Programs, then Open All Users. Make sure you create in that folder shortcuts for all your desired entry points (e.g., one shortcut for word, one for excel etc.)
3. Capture and Diff with TurboStudio. Set your virtualization settings as desired.
4. Click Output File-->Browse, and select "All files(*.*)" in the Save as type list. Then enter a filename with the extension .dat

[image: Save as .dat-TurboStudio]

5. Build your app. You will now get a .dat file instead of an .exe
6. In the next step you must use ExeBuilder.exe. This file was originally hosted in csgotwisted.com. Do a google search for "2 utilities for spoon studio exebuilder" and it will most likely be the first result. Unfortunately, the link is dead now when I click it. So I uploaded the file to NitroFlare. You can find it [here](http://nitroflare.com/view/E6ABC285DEAC209/ExeBuilder.zip). Put it in the same folder as the .dat file and run it. It will create a shortcut with your executable. Sometimes it misses the icon, but it gives you the option to locate it manually.

I use TurboStudio often and I have found this way to be the most quick and reliable in allowing me to generate small executables and storing the virtual filesystem and registry in a .dat file. In addition, it has the advantage that it can get you multiple entry points and not only one, just like Thinapp does.

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been trying to figure this out for so long!

Comment: You are welcome. Feel free to upvote/accept the answer I provided.

Comment: Apologies, I'm fairly new to the site. How do I do those?

Comment: There is an up arrow, a down arrow and a checkmark at the left upper side of my answer. To accept click the checkmark, it turns green. To upvote, click the up arrow (also turns green).

Comment: Nevermind, figured it out. And I have this utility already. I just couldn't figure it out. I would place it where it needed to be, but it would ALWAYS tell me files were missing even though the studio didn't. Guess it was looking for a .dat file.

Comment: It may still give you a similar warning. Just ignore this warning. It will generate the shortcuts. Like I said, it also allows you to browse manually to the executables in order to get the icons right.

Comment: I would appreciate if you could also upvote the answer. This is typical in addition to accepting it. Just a heads up, since you are new here.